# Values missing: Overlaying points on boxplot subplots from a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, for-loop, pandas, matplotlib, boxplot

I have two dataframes: df1 with 5000 rows and 12 columns and df2 with a single row and identical 12 columns as df1. I would like to plot each column on a separate subplot as a boxplot with values from df1, and overlay it with scatter plots (just one value per boxplot) from df2.

UPDATE: I tried using a transposed df2 with a numerical index. The following code does not give me any error but only one value on the second boxplot is visible.. I can't see the rest

```
labels = df1.columns.values
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows = 3, ncols = 4,gridspec_kw=dict(hspace=0.4))
targets = zip(labels, axes.flatten())
for i, (col, ax) in enumerate(targets):
    print col
    pd.DataFrame(df1[col]).boxplot(ax=ax, return_tpe = 'axes')
    ax.scatter(df2.index[i], df2['mycol'].values[i])
ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

Tried attaching the image here but I am slow today...
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0Bhe_qx3BgGWkJUdE45UEJqSFk/view?usp=sharing

---

Using pandas plotting:

Getting boxplot subplots *only* is easy using

```
ax = df1.plot(subplots = True)
```

But I don't know how to specify y for the scatter plot

```
ax = df2.plot(x = df2.plot.index, y = ???, subplots = True)
```